# Minify JavaScript and CSS in Magento

Tags: php, javascript, ce-1.8.1.0, css, html

I analyzed my website on Gtmetrix.com for optimization and the result was this:

> There are 9 components that can be minified:

```
inline <script> tag #6
inline <script> tag #9
inline <script> tag #10
inline <script> tag #11
inline <script> tag #12
inline <script> tag #13
inline <script> tag #14
inline <script> tag #15
inline <script> tag #16
```

> Strip unnecessary characters from JavaScript and CSS to speed up
>   download times.

*i should add this: i tried to minifying css an js files with an extension already.*

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline scripts are JS code snippets inside you html output, between `<script></script>` tags. You can minify them separately (there're several tools available, such as http://jscompress.com/), although please note that some of them contain `<?php ?>` tags as well.

Comment: which folder/file should i search to find these files?
what kind of file are these?
@Pronto

Comment: They are all over the template. What you could do is to see what inline JS system the metrics tools is referring to and search / grep them. By the way, many of those are relatively small snippets, containing only couple of lines code.